# R_exclude rows with a column containing a value if multiple rows exist

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe "test" as below. I want to exclude all the rows of that person, if this person has "apple" in the "fruit" column, using R language.
I wrote:

```
filter(test, name != test$name[test$fruit=="apple"])
```

original "test" data frame

[image]

actual result

[image]

expected result

[image]

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> test
     name      fruit
1   kevin      apple
2   kevin       pear
3   kevin      peach
4    jack      apple
5    jack       pear
6    jack      peach
7    jack       kiwi
8   caleb grapefruit
9   caleb       kiwi
10  caleb       pear
11 justin  pineapple
12 justin      grape
13 justin watermelon
14 justin       kiwi
```

First, we find the all the 'name' which have 'apple' as a fruit.

```
 df=unique(test$name[test$fruit=="apple"])

> df
[1] kevin jack 
Levels: caleb jack justin kevin
```

Now we need to remove rows from rows from **test** where *name* is same as those in **df**, i.e 'kevin' or 'jack'.

```
test1= test[ (!(test$name %in% df)),]

> test1
     name      fruit
8   caleb grapefruit
9   caleb       kiwi
10  caleb       pear
11 justin  pineapple
12 justin      grape
13 justin watermelon
14 justin       kiwi
```

Ofcourse we can write this in a single line :

```
test2=test[(!(test$name %in% (unique(test$name[test$fruit=="apple"])))),]

> test2
     name      fruit
8   caleb grapefruit
9   caleb       kiwi
10  caleb       pear
11 justin  pineapple
12 justin      grape
13 justin watermelon
14 justin       kiwi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple ways.

In base R :

```
subset(test, !ave(fruit == 'apple', name, FUN = any))

#   name     fruit
#4 Justin pineapple
#5 Justin     grape
```

Using `dplyr`

```
test %>% group_by(name) %>% filter(!any(fruit == 'apple'))
```

Or `data.table`

```
setDT(test)[, .SD[!any(fruit == 'apple')], name]
```

---

Another option in base R without grouping could be

```
subset(test, !name %in% unique(name[fruit == "apple"]))
```

**data**

```
test <- data.frame(name = c('Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Justin', 'Justin'), 
             fruit  =c('pineapple', 'apple', 'grape', 'pineapple', 'grape'))
```

Comment: many thanks Ronak!! I've learnt a lot from your answers! Cheers!